# Springboot 3.0 : Hiberanate/JPA 6 validation fail

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am having a method like this

```
 @Modifying( clearAutomatically = true )
    @Query( "update versioned LookupMaster set state =  'PUBLISHED' , value = newValue, newValue = null, updatedDate = current_timestamp where ( name = :tableName and state = 'MODIFIED')" )
    void commitLookupTableChanges( String tableName );
```

It was working before springboot 3 upgrade. After springboot upgrade to version 3.0.2 facing validation error like below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: The assignment expression type [java.lang.String] did not match the assignment path type [com.nokia.nsw.lookuptable.model.RowState] for the path [alias_2093546827.state] [update versioned LookupMaster set state =  'PUBLISHED' , value = newValue, newValue = null, updatedDate = current_timestamp where ( name = :tableName and state = 'MODIFIED')]
```

Code for Rowstate :

```
public enum RowState {
    MODIFIED, DELETED, PUBLISHED
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around `PUBLISHED` and `MODIFIED`. That is, change the query to:

```
update versioned LookupMaster set state = PUBLISHED, value = newValue, newValue = null, updatedDate = current_timestamp where ( name = :tableName and state = MODIFIED)
```

## UPDATE

So that is a bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16170 and we will get it fixed.

As a temporary workaround, you can write the query using a full-qualified name for the enum value:

```
update versioned LookupMaster set state = full.package.name.RowState.PUBLISHED, value = newValue, newValue = null, updatedDate = current_timestamp where ( name = :tableName and state = MODIFIED)
```

Comment: Its not working, after removing quotes new error as shown below

Comment: OK, that's simply a bug, see my update.

Comment: Thanks Gavin it worked. Now facing new issue, updating my question